# Is there a way to see the EE upgrade history?

Tags: ee2, ee2-upgrades

Normally I can put the pieces together by looking at upload dates, git history, and the `$config['app_version']` within /system/expressionengine/config/config.php. More often than not I cannot tell what previous version it was upgraded from.

This has to be logged somewhere in EE right? With dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is in the exp_update_log database table.  Date is the timestamp in UNIX format.